# Is there an import static equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, import, static-import

In java, one can import a class statically by calling `import static com.Abc`, for example. And then instead having to call `Abc.doSomething()` you can just call `doSomething()`. Is there an equivalent of this in Python, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just import the function directly. Consider the `timedelta` function in Python's `datetime` package. If I want to just import the function I use:

```py
from datetime.datetime import timedelta
```

Then I can use the function on its own.

Also, I can rename packages to simplify things. For instance, it is a common convention to import `matplotlib.pyplot` as `plt`, `pandas` as `pd`, and `seaborn` as `sns`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```